# Delete row when pressing button not working

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

So currently 160 servers are pulled from a database and stacked under each other:
`<tr>`
`<td>`
The  last `<td>` in this  row should trigger the removal of that specific row from the database but it doesn't and links me to the error page at this time.

Main code:

```
<?php

require_once "config/config.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM deployments";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['server'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['port'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><span class='badge badge-warning'>ERROR</span></td>";
echo "<td><a href='config/delete.php?id=". $row['server'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
echo "No records matching your query were found.";
}
} else{
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

?>
```

Delete.php page code:

```
<?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if(isset($_POST["server"]) && !empty($_POST["server"])){
    // Include config file
    require_once "config/config.php";

    // Prepare a delete statement
    $sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE server = ?";

    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_server);

        // Set parameters
        $param_server = trim($_POST["server"]);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: ../deployments.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter
    if(empty(trim($_GET["server"]))){
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

When the  `fa fa-trash` icon is clicked the row that icon shares with the `server` `name` `url` `port` should  be removed from the database.

Comment: 1. When you click the icon, it send a `GET` request, not `POST` request to delete.php. 2. The query of the request is `id`, not server -> the checking at the beginning of delete.php fail. Change `$_POST['server']` to` $_GET[id]`

Comment: You should define `$param_server` first then use it in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`

Comment: Yea I've tried this but as soon as I replace `POST` with `GET` it doesn't work any longer. `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'config/config.php'`

Comment: Which mean your `if` work alright. That error means the path `config/config.php` is invalid. Check and make sure the file is there.

Comment: The `config/config.php` path is valid, haven't made changes to that path. (File is still there haha)

Comment: I saw that your `delete.php` is inside `config` folder, so the `require_once "config/config.php";` in `delete.php` should be `require_once "config.php";`

Comment: I've changed that now, but currently that hasn't solved the issue for removing the rows as I'm still getting the `Invalid Request Sorry, you've made an invalid request. Please go back and try again.` page whenever I'm trying delete a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some changes to the code myself, thanks for all the help, the removal is still not working and I keep getting the error message from the `error.php` page.

```
<?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])) {

$id = $_POST["id"];

// Include config file
require_once "config/config.php";

// Prepare a delete statement
$sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE id = '$id'";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

// Set parameters
$param_id = trim($_GET["id"]);

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

// Attempt to execute the prepared statement
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
// Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
header("location: ../deployments.php");
exit();
} else {
echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
}
}

// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
} else {
// Check existence of id parameter
if (empty(trim($_GET["id"]))) {
// URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
header("location: error.php");
exit();
}
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo trim($_GET["id"]); ?>"/>
<p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p><br>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Yes" class="btn btn-danger">
<a href="../dashboard.php" class="btn btn-default">No</a>
</p>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use $_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id'] instead of $_POST["server"]

Replace your Delete.php code with below code

```
    <?php
// Process delete operation after confirmation
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty($_GET["id"])) {
    // Include config file
    require_once "config/config.php";

    // Prepare a delete statement
    $sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE server = ?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

        // Set parameters
        $param_server = trim($_GET["id"]);

        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_server);

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            // Records deleted successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: ../deployments.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else {
    // Check existence of id parameter
    if (empty(trim($_GET["id"]))) {
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this but thenever I click the remove button it comes back with `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'config/config.php'`

Comment: you should check path of config.php  file.  may be it's not getting config/config.php file.

Comment: Changed it, works now but it still doesn't remove the content.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to...

```
// Process delete operation after confirmation

if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {

  $id = $_POST["id"];

  //Include config file

  require_once("config/config.php");

  //Prepare a delete statement

  $sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE server = '$id' ";
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Shehbaz, changing`$sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE server = ?";` to `$sql = "DELETE FROM deployments WHERE id = '$id' ";` helped, the removal is still not working but I'm not getting the code error which is nice! so thank you for that

Comment: @ShehbazBadi: The downvote is not from me but: 1. please format your answer for better readability 2. You suggest using string concatenation in SQL query which is vulnerable to SQL injection while the OP use `mysqi_prepare` and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` which is safer.